# Restrictions on creation of ACS namespace - Jun 30

Tags: azureservicebus, acs

As per this blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/acs-access-control-service-namespace-creation-restriction/  creation of new ACS enabled Service Bus namespace is restricted from Jun 30 2017. However, I am able to create them using powershell commands. Is there a change in the effective date?

I wrote to azurefeedback@microsoft.com a week back but didn't receive any response

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/06/01/upcoming-changes-to-acs-enabled-namespaces/):

> ACS Namespaces you create before June 30, 2017 will not be affected and will be fully supported, however, attempts to create new ACS enabled Service Bus, Event Hubs, or Relay namespaces using PowerShell, ARM templates, and our APIs after June 30 will fail.  If ACS support is vital for your business and you need to create ACS namespaces after this date please contact Azure Customer Support by opening a technical support ticket for options.  You will need to provide the subscription ID or IDs that you use for creating ACS namespaces to the support engineer that assists you.  Going forward please think about using Shared Access Signature (SAS) keys instead.

I'm also very strange you could create new ACS, I suggest you could contact Azure support or send email(acsfeedback@microsoft.com) to check the new ACS is as same as the ACS Namespaces created before June 30.

Besides, we don't suggest you use ACS, SAS is recommended over ACS, as it provides a simple, flexible, and easy-to-use authentication scheme for Service Bus. Applications can use SAS in scenarios in which they do not need to manage the notion of an authorized "user."

Comment: I wrote to acsfeedback@microsoft.about 10 days back and awaiting their response.
We have an existing scenario where we use ACS based solution and the notion of authorized user. We need to find an alternative

Comment: Have connect to the azure support? In my opinion, you just need make sure the ACS you have created will not be affected. As the article says, the ACS still could be used if the customer directly by opening a technical support ticket for options.

Comment: Contacted them via Twitter and they suggested me to post a query here. Thanks Brando. I realize that existing ACS will continue to work for a while. We are an ISV and we have this ACS based solution built into our offerings and we need to sell them going forward.